# Running a console application from the system32 folder

Tags: c#, windows, cmd, system32

I made a piece of software that makes it possible for me to delete folders recursively through a console and what I want to do is make it possible to reach the program from any directory using CMD.EXE.
When I try to copy the software to the System32 directory and then run it from CMD it gives me the following error:

> unable to find a version of the runtime to run this application

I tried building it as a 64 bit program but that didn't change anything. 
Is there something wrong with my code or is it the way I'm building it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want us to say? Since you're not showing the code, nor telling us what way you're building it, we can't answer. Oh well: rd /s.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just add the directory of your application to the system's "path" environment variable instead of copying it to system32?

Comment: Which framework versions do you have installed, and which does it intend to utilise?

Comment: @Tobias But that has nothing to do with the problem. If the program won't run from System32, it won't run from any other directory.

Comment: @Tobias I have never done that and I have no clue how that works.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment I'm using .NET 2 for this application.

Comment: @MrLister It does run from other directories but it just won't run if I put it in the system32 and try to run it globally (by running the program from a folder it isn't in)

Comment: @Mega1mpact http://www.devcha.com/2006/12/adding-folder-to-environment-path-under.html

Comment: Deltree does something similar & is built in I think.

Comment: everyone answering to add the path but NOBODY exaplained WHY it gives the error ONLY if run in system32 directory!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the required .NET runtime you specified in your project options or in `app.config` file through `<supportedRuntime>` is not found in the system.

In short, **the targeted .NET runtime for your application is not found on the system.**