# Open cmd.exe and then run my current console application

Tags: c#

Here's something that I want to achieve:

1. Lets say I'm preparing abc.exe (console application).
2. I want to invoke cmd.exe and then launch abc.exe through cmd. And I won't be keeping cmd.exe in my projects folder. I'll be using it from system32 folder from user's machine.

Is it possible?

Comment: So, you want `abc.exe` to launch `cmd.exe`, and then have that `cmd.exe` launch another copy of `abc.exe`?

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16978753/896276) answer for the details

Comment: You can use `Process.Start("cmd.exe")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you can use `Process.Start(pathToExe)` to launch a new process.

You can start your program in a new cmd with `cmd /C start "Title" "C:\path\to\app.exe"`:

```
string cmdPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), "cmd.exe");
string exePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
ProcessStartInfo newCmd = new ProcessStartInfo(cmdPath);
newCmd.Arguments = String.Format(@"/C start ""{0}"" ""{1}""", "WindowTitle", exePath);
Process.Start(newCmd);
```

You probably want some sort of conditional around that in order to not fork bomb yourself

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I'll take care of it.